# Spring Boot with Hibernate Search can't find org.hibernate.query.ParameterMetadata

Tags: spring-boot, lucene, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-search

I have a fairly straight forward Spring Boot 1.5.2 application using Hibernate Search. JPA stuff works just fine.

I get Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.query.ParameterMetadata when running a search.

The code looks somewhat like this. Used to run in Wildfly, but I'm migrating to Spring Boot.

```
       FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);

    QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
            .buildQueryBuilder()
            .forEntity(Customer.class)
            .get();

    org.apache.lucene.search.Query
            luceneQuery = qb.keyword()
                .wildcard()
                .onField("primaryParty.firstName")
                .andField("primaryParty.sureName")
                .andField("customerNumber")
                .matching(query.trim() + "*")
                .createQuery();
    javax.persistence.Query jpaQuery =
            fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Customer.class);

    List<Customer> result = jpaQuery.getResultList();
```

Hibernate Core 5.0.12 is pulled in via Spring Boot, but the class is not there.

According to this: https://cia.sourceforge.io/tattleTaleReport/jar/hibernate-search-orm-5.7.0.Final.jar.html

i should expect to find it in hibernate-search-orm 5.7.0.Final. But from what I can see this jar only contains the org.hibernate.search package and no org.hibernate.query package. Can't find the class in any other package in that jar either, but it exists in a number of other packages on the class path.

Is the problem

```
javax.persistence.Query
```

If so, what to use instead? Or is the problem elsewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hibernate Search `5.7.0.Final` [is only compatible with Hibernate ORM `5.2.3.Final` and later](http://hibernate.org/search/documentation/migrate/5.7/#requirements).
You should either:

- downgrade Hibernate Search to `5.6.1.Final`
- or upgrade Hibernate ORM to version `5.2.3.Final` or later. With Spring Boot, I'm afraid you would have to use and unstable version of Spring Boot, namely `2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`

**EDIT**: actually, it seems you can use Hibernate ORM 5.2+ with Spring Boot 1.5; see [this sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/1.5.x/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-hibernate52). Be careful to use `5.2.3.Final` or later, though (the sample uses `5.2.0.Final`, which won't work).

---

By the way, the link you provided only mentions `org.hibernate.query` because of OSGi support, which probably isn't relevant to you. It happens that `hibernate-search-orm` (the module integrating Hibernate Search to Hibernate ORM) both imports and re-exports the `org.hibernate.query` package, but it doesn't provide it itself.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue due to using 5.7.0.Final jar and it was not compatible. This issue got resolved by changing downgrade jar version.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.1.Final</version>
```